# How to find the integrating factor of this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wanted to know whether there exists any general method for finding the integrating factor of a given differential equation $$Pdx+Qdy=0$$ For example I have the following equation 
$$x^3dx+2(x^2-xy^2)dy=0$$ which is not exact.

So far , I've tried to find the integrating factor for for all the following cases :

1. If the IF is a function of x , I used the check whether $$\frac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}}{Q}$$ is a function only of x .
2. I checked whether $$\frac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}}{-P}$$ is a function of only y.
3. Also whether $$\frac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}}{Q+P}$$ is a function of x-y
4. Then if $$\frac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}}{_Px+Qy}$$ is a function of xy
5. If $$\frac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}}{\frac{yQ+xP}{y^2}}$$ is a function of $$\frac{x}{y}$$
6. And finally if $$\frac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}}{2(xQ-yP)}$$ is a function of $$x^2+y^2$$
   And none of the above cases turned to work in my example. So now I'm stuck , not only on this example but in finding the integrating factor of any other differential equation in general. Is there any method to know (and to find) what kind of form does the integrating factor have without having to try all the special cases. Any help would be appreciated , thank you.

Comment: You wrote : $\quad x^3dx+2(x^2-xy^2)dy=0\quad$Why don't you simplify by $x$ ? Check if there is no typo.

Comment: @JJacquelin You're right .